# Can a concrete porch be raised about 4 feet?

Tags: concrete, porch

I am restoring my grandparents 1930s farmhouse. It has a concrete front porch with 2 pillars holding up a roof. It's raised, sitting on cinder blocks, but is about 4 feet below the front door with concrete steps on top of the porch to reach the front door. Can the porch be raised to the level of the door, and the stairs be placed in front of the porch, or would it be cheaper to tear it out and redo everything?

Comment: Pictures will help.  Concrete steps are very heavy, a concrete porch is heavier so big machines to move them.  The pillars holding up the the roof is another problem.  Building a wooden deck near the level of the door on the concrete porch with new steps down to the ground.  Leave the porch as is and the pillars if in good condition also.  You might get four foot of storage under the deck.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the porch?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

Can it be - sure, just a matter of spending enough money.

Unless there's some particular reason to "raise" that particular slab of concrete, probably a lot less expense to leave it where it is and use it as a foundation for a platform 4 feet higher, if a platform 4 feet higher is what you actually want.

Tearing it out to build that new platform starting from new footings is probably a waste of money and effort, barring information you have not shared.

Comment: The concrete slab was poured by my grandfather in the 1960s. The pillars are 8 inch diameter metal oil field pipes painted black. The concrete steps are too shallow for an entryway with no landing and are a fall/tripping Hazzard. The concrete porch is 12 feet by 12 feet and appears to be approximately 6 inches thick and has a very smooth surface... it seemes to be very high quality concrete work. I hoped I could raise it to the level of the door. It is currently 1 foot off the ground, sitting on a cinderblock base. The threshold of the door is approximately 4 feet above the concrete porch.